# How to get video frame rate on Android?

Tags: android

I'm creating program on Android 5.0, in which i should get frame rate of video. This help me to correctly getting frames from this video for following processing.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution - import JavaCV and used FFMpeg:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videopath);

        try {
            grabber.start();
        } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double frameRate=grabber.getFrameRate();
```